# Why bit or operation will lead to sign extension but bit and won't?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I need to cast a byte to int in Java but I don't want sign extension so I did

```
byte b = -1
(int) (b & 0xF) // this returns 15, which is what I want
(int) (b | 0)   // this returns -1, which is essentially 0xFFFF, sign extension happens, not what I want
```

I thought the above two should give same results but it turns out that's not the case.
I must miss something in bit operations.

Comment: Doing an OR with `0` gives the other number. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: No. I meant I thought 0 | ((byte) -1) should be 15, but actually it was -1.

Comment: ORing zero with a value returns the value unchanged.

Comment: And Java's `byte` is signed, so you will always get sign extension when casting to `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to print the binary representation of those values and perform the binary operations on them

```
byte b = -1;
int a = (int) (b & 0xF); // this returns 15, which is what I want
int c = (int) (b | 0); // this returns -1, which is essentially 0xFFFF
System.out.println("b:" + Integer.toBinaryString(b));
System.out.println("a:" + Integer.toBinaryString(a));
System.out.println("c:" + Integer.toBinaryString(c));
System.out.println("0xF:" + Integer.toBinaryString(0xF));
```

prints

```
b:11111111111111111111111111111111
a:1111
c:11111111111111111111111111111111
0xF:1111
```

So `b & OxF` is

```
11111111111111111111111111111111
00000000000000000000000000001111  (AND)
--------------------------------
                            1111   (15)
```

and `b | 0` is

```
11111111111111111111111111111111
00000000000000000000000000000000   (OR)
--------------------------------
11111111111111111111111111111111   (-1)
```

[Hot Licks explains why the byte value `-1` is represented in binary as it is.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20278093/why-bit-or-operation-will-lead-to-sign-extension-but-bit-and-wont/20278201#comment30251680_20278093)

Comment: @SteveP. It links to HotLicks' comment.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that bitwise operators work on ints or longs, not bytes. `b & 0xF` is essentially treated as `((int)b) & ((int)0xF)`. You can trace it all from the JLS definitions of each operation.

- First [JLS 15.22.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.1) (which defines `&` and `|`) explains that when both operands are convertible to integer primitive types, "binary numeric promotion is first performed on the operands (§5.6.2)."
- [JLS 5.6.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2), in turn, says that unless either operand is a `float`, `double` or `long`, both values are widened to `int`.
- Finally, widening is defined in [JLS 5.1.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) and states that "widening conversion of a signed integer value to an integral type T simply sign-extends the two's-complement representation of the integer value to fill the wider format." Bytes are signed ([JLS 4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2)).

So, your `b` byte is widened to an `int` using sign extension before being AND'd or OR'ed with the right operand.

Note that this would imply that the result of `b & 0F` should be an `int`, not a `byte`. This is in fact the case (meaning that your explicitly casting it to `int` is superfluous). You can test this by auto-boxing it to an `Object` and then checking that object's type:

```
byte b = -1;
Object o = (b & 0xF); 
System.out.println(o.getClass());
// prints "class java.lang.Integer", not "class java.lang.Byte"
```